# Scrollbar needed on flex item, not main container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a left menu which has a fixed size and a main part which should take the remaining place and contain a table. A scrollbar must appear if the table is too large.

In order to achieve this, I use a flex-box and **it works well** :

[image]

See the code snippet :

```css
.h-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container {
  overflow-x:auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-container">

  <div class="left-container">Left menu</div>

  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
        <th>Column 6</th>
        <th>Column 7</th>
        <th>Column 8</th>
        <th>Column 9</th>
        <th>Column 10</th>
        <th>Column 11</th>
        <th>Column 12</th>
        <th>Column 13</th>
        <th>Column 14</th>
        <th>Column 15</th>
        <th>Column 16</th>
        <th>Column 17</th>
        <th>Column 18</th>
        <th>Column 19</th>
        <th>Column 20</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
          <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
          <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
          <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
          <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
          <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, I am trying to insert a banner at the top of the table. In order to achieve this, I wanted to use another flex-box (a vertical flex-box nested in the horizontal flex-box).

**Problem** : the `<table>` does not take 100% of its container's width anymore. Instead, it increases the size of its container in order to fit into it without scroll bars. Because of that, a new scroll bar appear on the main container.

[image]

See the code snippet :

```css
.h-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.v-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.banner {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  overflow-x:auto;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-container">

  <div class="left-container">Left menu</div>

  <div class="v-container">
  
    <div class="banner">
    Banner
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
          <th>Column 11</th>
          <th>Column 12</th>
          <th>Column 13</th>
          <th>Column 14</th>
          <th>Column 15</th>
          <th>Column 16</th>
          <th>Column 17</th>
          <th>Column 18</th>
          <th>Column 19</th>
          <th>Column 20</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In firefox and Chrome the table and container has the same width. In safari (9) the table is scrollable inside the container. You want the other browsers to render this like Safari?

Comment: @eye-wonder Thank you for your comment. I did not konw that the result was different in Safari. I added some screenshots so that every one sees the same result. As you can see, the first table is scrollable inside its container. This is what I would like to achieve in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Add `min-width: 0` to `.v-container` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e33rgm6x/)).

Tested in Chrome, FF and IE11.

---

### Explanation

You're bumping up against the ***implied minimum sizing algorithm*** of flex items.

This is a default setting that prevents a flex item from shrinking past the size of its content.

The defaults are...

- `min-height: auto`
- `min-width: auto`

...for flex items in column-direction and row-direction, respectively.

You can override these settings with:

- `min-height: 0`
- `min-width: 0`

---

*From the spec:*

> [**4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1... [read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

---

```css
.h-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container {
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.v-container {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;  /* NEW */
}


.banner {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-container">
    <div class="left-container">Left menu</div>
    <div class="v-container">
        <div class="banner">Banner</div>
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                    <th>Column 6</th>
                    <th>Column 7</th>
                    <th>Column 8</th>
                    <th>Column 9</th>
                    <th>Column 10</th>
                    <th>Column 11</th>
                    <th>Column 12</th>
                    <th>Column 13</th>
                    <th>Column 14</th>
                    <th>Column 15</th>
                    <th>Column 16</th>
                    <th>Column 17</th>
                    <th>Column 18</th>
                    <th>Column 19</th>
                    <th>Column 20</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using calc(100% - 300px) on the v-container and 100% width on the container.

```css
.h-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.v-container {
  /* flex: 1; */
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}

.banner {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  overflow-x:auto;
  /* flex:1;*/
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-container">

  <div class="left-container">Left menu</div>

  <div class="v-container">
  
    <div class="banner">
    Banner
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
          <th>Column 11</th>
          <th>Column 12</th>
          <th>Column 13</th>
          <th>Column 14</th>
          <th>Column 15</th>
          <th>Column 16</th>
          <th>Column 17</th>
          <th>Column 18</th>
          <th>Column 19</th>
          <th>Column 20</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Calc vs flex browser support
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: I don't know whether it is the cleanest solution (imho, flex-box are intended to do the "calc" part) but it works like a charm. If no better answer is given, i will accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do another `flexbox` in the right div but in columns:

```css
.h-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.v-container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x:auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.banner {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  overflow-x:auto;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-container">

  <div class="left-container">Left menu</div>

  <div class="v-container">
  
    <div class="banner">
    Banner
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
          <th>Column 11</th>
          <th>Column 12</th>
          <th>Column 13</th>
          <th>Column 14</th>
          <th>Column 15</th>
          <th>Column 16</th>
          <th>Column 17</th>
          <th>Column 18</th>
          <th>Column 19</th>
          <th>Column 20</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
            <td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work only if there is `overflow-x:auto;` both on `container` and `v-container`. Do you know what is the reason behind that?

Comment: I think it is something like this: the div `.v-container`  need overflow for clip the content that exceeded , this affects the banner and the table, we want leave out the banner so div `.container` needs overflow that only affects the table.

Comment: the div `.container` get the width of the table, overflow only in this div has no effect, hasn't a width to clip the table. I do not know if I have explained well